# Can't use context.read() from inside FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod + StateNotifier as my state management solution and I want to call a method when the FloatingActionButton is pressed but I can't use `context.read()` to access the provider. Also from inside my AppBar I can't use it. Here is my code:

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**homepage.dart**

```
final homeProvider = StateNotifierProvider<HomeNotifier, HomeState>(
    (ref) => getIt<HomeNotifier>());

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: HomePageAppBar(),
      body: ProviderListener<HomeState>(
        provider: homeProvider,
        onChange: (context, state) {
          state.errorMessage.fold(() {}, (error) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text(error),
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        child: Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
          final state = watch(homeProvider);
          if (state.isLoading)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: state.items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                MyCard(playlist: state.items[index]),
          );
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: CreateButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

**create_button.dart**

```
class CreateButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add_rounded,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        // here I want to use context.read(homeProvider)
      },
    );
  }
}
```

However, if I don't create a separate widget for the FloatingActionButton but instead I put it just inside the Scaffold, I can use context.read.

Comment: Have you imported riverpod into `create_button.dart`?

Comment: Added my comment as an answer for future readers, pretty common problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading providers from context is only available when the file you're working with has riverpod imported. Double-check your imports and hopefully that's it!

Comment: Just as an update for those new to Riverpod (as I am, so have just worked this out myself), as of version 1.0 (I think) there is a breaking change that you no longer use context.read but use ref.read()